# Add an external TableView inside a small view on the Main Screen

Tags: iphone

I have a simply MainWindow file created by the Interface Builder in black background. Inside this plain view, I've added from top to bottom a small view (300x100), a textLabel and a couple of buttons.

In the MainApplication.h I've defined:

IBOutlet RoundRectView* smallView;
IBOutlet UILabel* label;

In the MainApplication.h I've @synthesized these variables and with that:

[label setText:@"Test"];

I can see all in my screen and it works perfect.

Now my problem:

I want to add a table with two rows inside my small white view, and what I've done is:

1. Create a tableController.h who's the delegate and the data source:

> @interface IncomeExpenseController :
>   UITableViewController
>    {  IBOutlet
>   UITableView* smallTable;  NSArray
>   *content; }
>
> @property (nonatomic, retain)
>   UITableView *smallTable; @property
>   (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *content;
>
> @end

2. Create the .m file with:

> @synthesize smallTable; @synthesize
>   content;
>
> - (void)viewDidLoad {
>     [super viewDidLoad];  content = [[NSArray alloc]
>     initWithObjects:@"Item1", @"Item2",
>     nil]; }
> - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView
>     *)tableView {
>     // Return the number of sections.
>     return 0; }
> - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
>     {
>     // Return the number of rows in the section.
>     return 2; }
>
> // Customize the appearance of table
>   view cells.
>   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
>   *)indexPath {
>
> ```
> static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
>
> UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
> if (cell == nil) {
>     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
> ```
>
> initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
>   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
>   autorelease];
>       }    NSLog(@"inside cell");
>
> ```
> // Configure the cell...    cell.textLabel.text = [content
> ```
>
> objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
>
> ```
> return cell; }
> ```

Now in the Interface Builder, I drag and drop a UITableView inside the white small view and drag and drop a Table View Controller along with the File Owner's window and I do these connections:

1. Class of the Table View Controller to tableController
2. Outlets:
   DataSource and Delegate to my Table Controller
3. Referencing Outlets:
   customTable and View to my Table Controllers

When I execute, I can see the lines of the table view but with no content, I cannot see the NSLog either but if I put a NSLog inside the viewDidLoad I can see it.

I'm really new (2 days) on that and any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Solved.

First of all, the TableView is grouped so I must return almost one section. Second, from the Interface Builder, I had to link the "view" from the Table to my external controller.

Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

First of all, the TableView is grouped so I must return almost one section.
Second, from the Interface Builder, I had to link the "view" from the Table to my external controller.

Now it works perfectly.